# generate invoice & shipment programmatically if extension is enable in store->configuration

Tags: magento2, invoice

I want to generate invoice and shipment automatically when store->configuration Enable Invoice option is enabled ... I've already generated invoice and shipment automatically but now i need to generate it only when that option is enable and i've to check whether active payment method and my payment option is true. like following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIged.png)

Any option is there!?with which i can add this condition in my observer!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make helper file like this

```
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    const ENABLE = 'section/group/field';
    const VALUE = 'section/group';

    public function isEnable()
    {
       return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::ENABLE, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    }
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::VALUE ,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

And call this function in your observer file to check extension enable or disable and get your all configuration data

Comment: Thank You @Arjun Soni. I'll try it for sure...and i'll be grateful when this work!